# Get frame info for outer scope, but only invest the time in inner scope

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, inspect

I have the following scenario, where I want to get frame info for the scope above my scope.

```py
def outer():
    # This is really slow.
    frames = inspect.stack()

    def inner():
        # I would like to "pay for it" here instead.
        print(frames)

    return inner
```

The call `inspect.stack()` is very slow, so I would like to do it only when I really need to, meaning when someone calls `inner`. But if I move it inside the inner function, I would get different frames than what I need.

Alternatively if I could get all of `frame.filename` and `frame.lineno`, (for each `frame` for the outer scope), fast in some other way - that is also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to delay the work until the `inner` call, because the information you want doesn't exist any more at that point. If you try to delay the work until `inner`, you'll only be able to retrieve information about the state of the program at the time of the `inner` call, which will be a completely different state than at the time of the `outer` call.

That said, `inspect.stack` is pretty slow, and you only care about file name and line number information. `inspect.stack` is doing a lot of work you don't want. If all you want is file name and line number information, you can use [`traceback.extract_stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack), which should be a lot faster.

You can go even faster by extracting the information you want manually:

```
def do_it_manually():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    results = []
    while frame:
        results.append((frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno))
        frame = frame.f_back
    return results
```

This gives a list of `(filename, lineno)` tuples, starting from `do_it_manually`'s caller. It's several orders of magnitude faster than `inspect.stack` when I test it with a deep stack.

Comment: This is great, thanks! also if you're interested this is what I'm using it for: https://github.com/hyroai/gamla/pull/113